# azure functions POST method is not allowed

Tags: azure-functions

I developed a web api <https://{api name}.azurewebsites.net> using azure functions and tested it locally using VS Code using the POST method and it works exactly as I need it to. However when I deploy it (also from VS Code) to prod and test the POST method from postman, I receive a **405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED** and it looks like it only works with a GET. I can see the app is up and running from the portal and cannot understand why it is restricted to GET only when i have the following set up:

```json
# function.json

{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help appreciated.
I am also confused about how the web api is deployed under APP Services and not under Function APP. I am guessing Function APP comes under APP services?

Comment: There are no problem with your `function.json`, could you please tell me that how you deploy your `Azure function`?

Comment: @FrankGong I realized that instead of deploying using the option under Function App, I erroneously deployed under App Service Plan. The end point when deployed correctly should be https://{api name}.azurewebsites.net/api/functionname.

Answer (score 0):

I deployed originally like this:
[image]

But it should have been under this:
[image]

Now it works as desired.